# Excel convert hyperlink formulas to links with friendly names

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I need to convert columns of cells with HYPERLINK formulas into cells with just the friendly_name hyperlinked to link_location.  For instance, =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","+")&"&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl","G images") to a cell that just has G images in it and is hyperlinked to the hyperlink that the formula produces, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search+term&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl.  I can do this by pasting into Word and pasting back into Excel, but I need to do it within Excel, whether by some copy/paste trick or a macro.

Comment: Can you post a sample table/output of what you're expecting to see?

Comment: I want the HYPERLINK formula converted, hopefully via macro, to the same format as if I right clicked on a cell, clicked Hyperlink..., put "G images" in the "Text to display:" field and "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search+term&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl" in the "Address:" field.

Comment: Ohh - So, when looking at the cell, you **don't** want a formula to be in the cell, but the text "G images", linked to the URL?

Comment: Is the URL always going to be a Google one, like your example?

Comment: I didn't see this, but no, it most definitely will not always be google.  I'm starting to think I should rethink the original formulas and use a different pathway to achieve what I want, as I didn't think it would be this complicated to do what I need to do since I could so easily paste into word and back and get the results I need.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does the code I gave as an answer not work? If you can give a few misc. examples of the URL types, and how they'll looks, I'm sure a macro would work.  Maybe even just have a macro do the "pasting and copying to/from word" for you.

Comment: Movie Name IMBD Wikipedia Rotten Tomatoes Google
Batman v Superman http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=Batman+v+Superman https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Batman+v+Superman http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=Batman+v+Superman https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Batman+v+Superman

Comment: Others are more complicated though, so a url specific one won't work. Here are formula examples =IF(LOOKUP(A106,ISB_Lookup!$A$3:$A$4739)=A106,HYPERLINK("http://florida.plantatlas.usf.edu/plant.aspx?id="&LOOKUP(A106,ISB_Lookup!$A$3:$A$4739,ISB_Lookup!$C$3:$C$4739),"ISB Atlas"), HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",E106),""))  =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q="&SUBSTITUTE($A3," ","+")&"+trailer")

Comment: These make clickable links, but the end goal is to make links to several website searches open from just selecting a cell from a list for the search term and then clicking a button to activate a macro that will open them all.  This is an example of a macro that works with links made with formulas and then pasted into Word and pasted back, but that will not work with Hyperlink formula or text urls for some reason.  Thanks very much for all of your help with this and sorry if I have not been clear.

Comment: Sub selectLinks()
'
' selectLinks Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 4).Resize(1, 9).Select
    
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
        hl.Follow
    Next hl
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Found this at Chihiro, Excel Ninja:
One way to do it is to copy and paste out to Word Doc.
And then copy and paste back from Word Doc to Excel. This will retain link and title/friendly name.

For large documents or many columns with links, this will be less practical of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, try this (adjust `rng` as necessary):

edit: New code, per comment below:

```
Sub replace_Hyperlink_Formula_With_Text()
Dim linkWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
Dim linkText$, url$, address$, subPart$
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim commaPos&

Set linkWS = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to the sheet name that has =Hyperlink("http://...","Link")
Set newWS = Sheets.Add
newWS.Name = "Links Only" ' or whatever you want the non-Hyperlink Formula sheet to be called.

Set rng = linkWS.Range("A1:A2") ' Edit this as needed

For Each cel In rng
    linkText = cel.Value
    commaPos = InStrRev(cel.Formula, ",")

    subPart = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(linkWS.Range("A2"), " ", "+")
    url = Mid(cel.Formula, WorksheetFunction.Search("(", cel.Formula) + 2, commaPos)
    Debug.Print url

    commaPos = InStrRev(url, ",")
    url = Left(url, commaPos - 2)
    url = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(url, "&", ";", 1)
    Debug.Print url


    ' Now, trim SUBSTITUTE out of it
    Dim leftUrl$, rightURL$
    leftUrl = Left(url, WorksheetFunction.Search(";", url) - 2)
    rightURL = Mid(url, WorksheetFunction.Search("&", url) + 2, Len(url))
    url = leftUrl & subPart & rightURL
    Debug.Print url
  '  cel.ClearContents
    address = cel.address
    newWS.Range(address).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=newWS.Range(address), address:=url, TextToDisplay:=linkText
Next cel

End Sub
```

It's kludgy, but it should succeed in parsing out the `&Substitute...&` part, and replacing it with what's in `A2`.

Comment: That worked beautifully; thanks!  Is there an easy way to modify this so that it would create these hyperlinked cells on another sheet in corresponding cells and leave the formulas in the original sheet?  That's not absolutely necessary, but would be more convenient for users now that I think about it and sorry for not thinking about that before.

Comment: @DaveA - Yeah of course, that's no problem. I'll edit the code, and if it works for you, would you kindly mark as the answer (click the check outline left of the post)?

Comment: Sorry, just found out it's not making the urls correctly. Outputting something like https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22&SUBSTITUTE(A

Comment: @DaveA - D'oh, I forgot you're using a formula to put the URL together. See my edited code, it should get you going more.  I'm also assuming your `A2` has the `/` in it, for the URL to work. If this doesn't work, can you perhaps post a sampling of your data table?  (mainly what's in `A2`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but not sure if this is resolved.
Try the following.

```
Sub convert_hyperlink_formula_to_hyperlink_cell()
    Dim address_string As String, display_string As String
    Dim current_range As Range

    For Each current_range In Selection
        address_string = current_range.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        display_string = current_range.Value
        current_range.ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=current_range, Address:=address_string, TextToDisplay:=display_string
    Next current_range
End Sub
```